# Strore urls in a separate file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am working on Angular Routing and have URLs hardcoded directly in my javascript file. However, I would need to keep these URLs in a separate file, where should I keep it preferably? I can't map them with variables in XML or java given that I am working on CQ Adove 5 environment.

1. Is it possible to do so in another JS file where I can have mapping between variables and URLs as key-value pair? or would it be better to do so in a JSON?
2. How can I pick up the values from one JS and access in another JS? I would like to have a variable xyz in place of "/content/abc.html".

**Code**
.when('/', {
                templateUrl: '**/content/abc.html**',
                controller: 'tempController'
            })

to 
.when('/', {
                templateUrl: **abc**,
                controller: 'tempController'
            })

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TemplateUrl takes either a string or a function that returns a string, simply use an anonymous function like so ->

```
function() {
    return myPartialObject.abc;
}
```

As to your first issue, why don't you create a factory for myPartialObject which contains all of your template -> string mappings, inject it into the routeprovider and access this for your template urls? It can be in a separate file as you wish and angular takes care of all the injections etc.

Edit - here's a sample file retrieval function

```
var retrieveFile = function (url) {
    var promise = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        headers: {Accept: '*/*', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    });
    return promise;
};
```

So then you'd attach a .then to promise and do what you want with the data ( in your case set the object your service is returning to the json mapping, angular has some pretty nice json functions to help out with this )

```
retrieveFile("/myjson.json").then(function (data) {
    SetUpMyVariables(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @LinuxN00b. I got your point of using services and then injecting in routeprovider. But inside the service, I'd still need to pass the variable to a function which will then return the desired url back from where? Would you suggest to call a json having variable:url mapping inside the function?

Comment: You can have it as a mapping in the file if that's easier, if you want to read an actual json file then that's done pretty simply as well using $http service, just make sure to do it as part of the factory initialization and to use then to set it to your variable( assuming that it is a static read-once file)

Comment: updated answer with sample retrieval in case I've misunderstood